# Construct list in one-line while-loop - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is while loop:

```
def func1(foo)
    bar = []
    while len(bar) < foo: 
        bar.append([])
    return bar
```

I have tried to fit my code in one line:

```
def func1(foo)
    bar = []
    return (bar.append([]) while len(bar) < foo)
```

But when i run it, i have the following error:

```
return (bar.append([]) while len(bar) < foo)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: What in the world made you think that was valid Python syntax? You can't just make sh*t up and expect it to work!

Comment: `How can I fix that?` Simply Don't try `to fit my code in one line`

Comment: That is valid for `if` and not `while`

Comment: @karthikr wrong. You're probably thinking of the ternary operator, which is different from an if statement; also it always requires an `else` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be coming from a Ruby background where you can write things such as

```
> i = 0
> i += 1 while i < 10
> i
=> 10
```

**Solution:** Instead use a list comprehension and

```
def func1(foo):
    return [ [] for _ in range(foo) ]
```

Which says "give me a new list, foo times"

**DO NOT** attempt to use the `[[]] * foo` shorthand because all of the entries in the list will actually refer to the same sublist

```
>>> l = [[]] * 10
>>> l[0].append(2) # now every sublist has a 2 in it.
>>> l
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

or the similar use of `extend`

```
>>> foo =6
>>> bar = ['abc']
>>> bar.extend([[]] * foo)
>>> bar
['abc', [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> bar[1].append(2)  # same problem
>>> bar
['abc', [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

If you're absolutely set on a **one-line while loop**, the way to do it would be

```
def func1(foo)
    bar = []
    while len(bar) < foo: bar.append([])
    return bar
```

But the list comprehension is the simplest, fastest, most pythonic solution

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't have a one line while loop.
But you can use a [comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
return [[] for x in range(foo)]
```

Comment: foo is an integer not a list

Comment: Ok, then no `len` is needed (I haven't noticed that).